# Identify first match position in a string

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, substring

I have a character string ("00010000") and need to identify which position do we see the first "1". (This tells me which month a customer is active)

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id  <- c(1:5)
seq <- c("00010000","00001000","01000000","10000000","00010000")
df <- data.frame(id,seq)
```

I would like to create a new field identifying the first_month_active for each id.

I can do this manually with a nested ifelse function:

```
    df$first_month_active <-
        ifelse(substr(df$seq,1,1)=="1",1,
        ifelse(substr(df$seq,2,2)=="1",2,
        ifelse(substr(df$seq,3,3)=="1",3,       
        ifelse(substr(df$seq,4,4)=="1",4,
        ifelse(substr(df$seq,5,5)=="1",5,99 )))))
```

Which gives me the desired result:

```
  id  seq        first_position
  1   00010000   4
  2   00001000   5
  3   01000000   2
  4   10000000   1
  5   00010000   4
```

However, this is not an ideal solution for my data, which contains 36 months.

I would like to use a loop with an ifelse statement, however I am really struggling with syntax

```
for (i in 1:36) {
ifelse(substr(df$seq,0+i,0+i)=="1",0+i,
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think `strsplit` might help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Skip the loop and the `ifelse`:

```
9 - nchar(as.numeric(seq))
## [1] 4 5 2 1 4
```

This won't work the same in your data.frame because you coerced `seq` to factor implicitly, so just do:

```
9 - nchar(as.numeric(as.character(df$seq)))
## [1] 4 5 2 1 4
```

Edit: Just for fun, since Frank didn't convert his comment into an answer, here's `strsplit` solution:

```
# from original vector
sapply(strsplit(seq, "1"), nchar)[1,] + 1
## [1] 4 5 2 1 4

# from data.frame
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$seq), "1"), nchar)[1,] + 1
## [1] 4 5 2 1 4
```

Comment: the first one worked for me (clever solution), but that one makes alot of sense too. wonderful!

Comment: The apparent string is "00010000" but it should be noted this could be double characters depending on encoding. In that case `strtrim` should be called first giving the expected length otherwise the `strsplit` may not have the expected results.

Comment: Ah, neat trick. I was thinking of the messier `sapply(strsplit(c("01001","10000"),"",fixed=TRUE),function(x)which(x=="1")[1])`

Answer (score 12):

Or try the `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)
stri_locate_first_fixed(df$seq, "1")[, 1]
## [1] 4 5 2 1 4
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `gregexpr`.

```
> unlist(gregexpr(pattern=1,seq,fixed=T))
[1] 4 5 2 1 4
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that if there is more than one "1" it will report both instead of just the first one. Use `regexpr` to just get the first one.

Answer (score 8):

The following could do this job:

```
library(stringr)
str_locate(pattern ='1',seq)
```

Answer (score 6):

Some comparisons:

```
library(stringi)
library(stringr)

seq <- c("00010010","00001000","10000010","10000000","00010000")
seq2 <- rep(seq, 5e6)

system.time(regexpr("1", seq2))
   user  system elapsed 
   4.78    0.03    4.82

system.time(9-nchar(as.numeric(as.character(seq2))))
   user  system elapsed
   34.89    0.18   35.52

system.time(str_locate(pattern ='1',seq2))
   user  system elapsed 
   6.17    0.21    6.53

system.time(stri_locate_first_fixed(seq2, "1")[, 1])
   user  system elapsed
   1.68    0.15    1.84

system.time(nchar(seq2)-round(log10(as.numeric(seq2))))
   user  system elapsed
   7.67    0.09    7.86

system.time(nchar(sub('1.*', '', seq2))+1)
   user  system elapsed
   14.61    0.11   14.93
```

Comment: You should use `microbenchmark` for timings. It is more reliable than `system.time`.

Comment: @Thomas all the benchmarks were in *seconds* differences, there is no need in `mocrobenchmark`.

Comment: You could add "fixed = TRUE" in `regexpr` to improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

Another one, using `log`:

```
  nchar(seq)-round(log10(as.numeric(seq)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `sub`

```
nchar(sub('1.*', '', seq))+1
#[1] 4 5 2 1 4
```